# Go how can i efficient split string into parts

Tags: string, go, split

i am fighting with a string splitting. I want to split string by *wildcard*s into a slice, but this slice should contain this wildcards as well.

For example: `/applications/{name}/tokens/{name}` should be split into `[/applications/ {name} /tokens/ {name}]` etc.

Here is a sample code i wrote, but it is not working correctly, and i don't feel good about it either.

https://play.golang.org/p/VMOsJeaI4l

There are some example routes to be tested. Method `splitPath` split path into parts and display both: before and after.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't want to use `strings.Split`? https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split

Comment: ye becouse i want `separator` to be included and in my case separator can be different for example `{name}/{surname}`. You dont rly know what string is between `{}` and how many of them there is

Comment: I still think you'll get the best result from using strings.Split, but you may be interested in writing a parser; they're fun and Rob Pike has a relatively famous talk explaining how to write a custom lexical scanner, which is fun too.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirements but is this what you're looking for? https://play.golang.org/p/qcqBgld2_I

Comment: yes, perfect with a quick look i think it works as i wanted. Thanks, i will now do parser/lexer solution as @JohnWeldon mention and then compare performance of this two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
var validPathRe = regexp.MustCompile("^(/{[[:alpha:]]+}|/[-_.[:alnum:]]+)+$")
var splitPathRe = regexp.MustCompile("({[[:alpha:]]+}|[-_.[:alnum:]]+)")

func splitPath(path string) parts{
    var retPaths parts

    if !validPathRe.MatchString(path) {
        return retPaths
    }

    retPaths = splitPathRe.FindAllString(path, -1)

    return retPaths
}
```

I made this by creating two regular expressions, one to check if the path was valid or not, the other to extract the various parts of the path and return them. If the path is not valid it will return an empty list. The return of this will look like this:

```
splitPath("/path/{to}/your/file.txt")
["path" "{to}" "your" "file.txt"]
```

This doesn't include the '/' character because you already know that all strings in the return but the last string is a directory and the last string is the file name. Because of the validity check you can assume this.